# How to inject the Construtor with string and interface parameters in ASP.NET 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, structuremap

I have a constructor like the below:

```
 public JITService(string baseAdress, IHttpClientProvider    clientProvider)
 {
 }
```

For only one interface as parameter, can inject in Startup.cs like:

```
 services.AddTransient<IHttpClientProvider, HttpClientProvider>();
```

For only one string as paramener, can inject like:

```
services.AddTransient<IJITService, JITService>((_) => new JITService(""));
```

I do know how to do by third part like StructureMap:

```
config.For<IJITService>()
.Use<JITService>()
.Ctor<string>("baseAdress")
.Is(_JITService);
```

But how to do in ASP.NET 5.0 project? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works as below:

```
services.AddScoped<IJITService>(sp => new JITService(Configuration["Data:Services:JITService"], sp.GetService<IHttpClientProvider>()));
```

Comment: Answered your own question. Nice jorb! :)  Mark it as answered and you're all done.